# How can i host java udp program for my android application?

Tags: java, hosting

i am developing an android application in which the server side execution is done using a simple java udp program.i want to know how i can host this application because i need a static ip server to run the java program.can i run my java program in a server.is it possible if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write a listener in some language (PHP, Java, Etc.). As for a static ip address, you can also look at a dynamic ip redirection service like no-ip;

http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html

You can use a personal machine thats always online, or you can try to use a shared hosting plan that allows you to have a listening port open. A web service will likely be easier to work with than having some custom UDP/TCP connection.